# Spotify get other user's currently playing track

Tags: c#, spotify

I want to get datas of other user's currently playing track. is it possible ? i can take my own.

```
  using (var hc = new HttpClient())

        {

            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "my token");





            using (var music = await hc.GetAsync($"https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/currently-playing"))
            {
                music.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 

                string jsonString = await music.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                // TODO: parse json and return true, if the returned array contains the stream
                JObject o = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/player/) you can not get the currently playing track for any user, you only have access for the user which has been authorized.

However, if you are able to get the user to authorize your app with the following access scope [user-read-currently-playing](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/scopes/#user-read-currently-playing) then the app can call the same end point `/me/player/currently-playing` on your behalf and pass along the track that is currently being played to you.